# How to check where gradle is downloading its dependencies from?

Tags: maven, gradle, build.gradle, artifactory

I have a project using gradle from building and due to some recent jcenter issues, we want to move all our dependencies to our artifactory. Now i have all the configuration ready and declared inside the gradle build files. I have also removed all traces of other maven repositories.

```
repositories {

    maven {
        url "${artifactory_contextUrl}/repo_name-generic"
        credentials {
            username = "${artifactory_user}"
            password = "${artifactory_password}"
        }
    }
}
```

After doing a gradle clean build, i expected a lot of errors as i have never added those dependencies to our artifactory repo, but none came. The project builds fine and i can see them being downloaded.

My question now is, why is it working?
Is there a way i can check from which source the dependencies are coming from?

Also in artifactories GUI i cannot locate the packages inside the specified repo

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

1. rm -rf ~/.gradle/caches
2. ./gradlew assembleDebug -i > ~/Desktop/dump
3. search dependency lib in dump file to check where it was downloaded from

For example, flexbox-2.0.1 was downloaded from jcenter:
[image]

Comment: No need to remove your entire cache - just run `./gradlew assembleDebug --refresh-dependencies -i` instead

Answer (score 1):

If you ant to print the repositories a project is using, the following task will do it for you:

```
task printRepos {
    doFirst {
        project.repositories { repositories -> 
            repositories.forEach { repo -> 
                println("${repo.name}: ${repo.url}")
            }           
        }
    }
}
```

If you add it to your gradle build and invoke it `gradle printRepos`, you should get the repositories printed out

For more information regarding the API, check: https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/dsl/RepositoryHandler.html
https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html

Also thanks to Bjorn for pointing out the `doFirst/doLast` problem.

Comment: It should probably be wrapped in a `doFirst`/`doLast` block so it prints out the result in the execution phase. Otherwise, a plugin or other task might change the repository list after this task has been configured (in the configuration phase).