# How to find where gradle fetches dependencies in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

When I run gradle task myApp:androidDependencies, I get the following:

```
debugCompileClasspath - Dependencies for compilation
+--- com.serenegiant:common:4.1.1@aar
+--- androidx.databinding:databinding-runtime:7.4.2@aar
+--- androidx.databinding:databinding-adapters:7.4.2@aar
+--- androidx.databinding:databinding-common:7.4.2@jar
+--- androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0@aar
+--- com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0@aar
+--- androidx.preference:preference:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.1@aar
+--- androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1@aar
+--- androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1@aar
...
```

Is there a way to find out exactly which repositories these dependencies come from? This question is related to [another question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76307882/error-could-not-resolve-all-files-for-configuration-appdebugruntimeclasspath). The dependency com.serenegiant:common:4.1.1 works fine with this project, but does not work with another project which cannot find it. It fails with the following error:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionNotFoundException: Could not find com.serenegiant:common:4.1.1.
Searched in the following locations:
  - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/serenegiant/common/4.1.1/common-4.1.1.pom
  - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/serenegiant/common/4.1.1/common-4.1.1.pom
  - https://jitpack.io/com/serenegiant/common/4.1.1/common-4.1.1.pom
```

Any tip will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: maybe this could help ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/72742119/6899896

Comment: @M.Ricciuti Thank you for trying to help. I tried it and I also tried " ./gradlew --info --refresh-dependencies" prior to it, but got errors. See the update of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76307882/error-could-not-resolve-all-files-for-configuration-appdebugruntimeclasspath

Answer (score 0):

As I see from github, this library is published as an `.aar` , not published to other repositories   https://github.com/duvitech/libcommon/tree/master/repository/com/serenegiant/common
then, you must download `.aar` file and import it as a library module. See [how to add aar to your project](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library#psd-add-aar-jar-dependency)

Comment: Thank you for trying to lend a hand. The library works fine without being downloaded. See this question of mine: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76307882/error-could-not-resolve-all-files-for-configuration-appdebugruntimeclasspath